# What are the Amazon.com Product Advertising API's request limits?

Tags: api, web-services, amazon-product-api

I would like to create a WS which search a product on web page amazon.com. I have a simple question. 
How much can I send request to amazon from one IP?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Amazon.com Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) to `Advertise`, `search for Amazon products`, `discover Amazon products`. Regarding the usage limits and requests check out  [Usage Guidelines : Product Advertising API License Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html#usage)